# Vim: Find in Buffers capabilities that resembles those in TextMate

Tags: vim, textmate, macvim

In TextMate you can drag one or more files onto the icon and use "Find in Project" to search those files, can this be replicated for the current open buffers in Vim?

Answer (score 2):

grep
lgrep
vimgrep
lvimgrep

These commands might help you.
Check here, If this is what you are looking for.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim

Answer (score 1):

I like [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) which has a very fast and easy to use "search in buffers" function.

[Ack.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) works in a sort-of-similar way but is file-system based.

Comment: capability to search buffers ala Ack is pretty much what I'm looking for, MultipleSearch is the closest to my needs for the time being...

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Vim does not have project management features, but as mentioned by sat you can use various grep command to find something in files or sub-directories.

However you can install [project.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) which is a plugin providing the management of multiple files (including search a la Textmate)