# Is there an Vim/MacVim equivalent for TextMate's Find in Project?

Tags: vim, macvim

I was using TextMate now I am using MacVim, the only thing I miss from TextMate is the "Find in Project" functionality, is there any Vim plugin providing this functionality?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate. Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/5290617/557306 and its answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [EasyGrep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438) might do most of what you are looking for. It does a extension sensitive search of the current directory on down.

I use it a lot for finding things in projects.

Answer (score 6):

I think [Project.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) lets you search in its "project" but I never really liked the idea of having several files from different parts of my filesystem magically grouped in a virtual project.

If — like me — all the files of your project happen to be in the same "real" folder [Ack.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) and [EasyGrep.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438) both work very well.

[LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) is also very good for searching in buffers.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [ack.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) to do this.

You may need to install ack beforehand unless you already have it installed. There are installation instructions on the vim-scripts page, but here's what I did (I don't use macports):

```
curl http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone > /tmp/ack
sudo mv /tmp/ack /usr/local/bin/ack
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/ack
```

Which I have in a setup file for my vim configs [here](https://github.com/billturner/vimfiles/blob/master/Rakefile#L45).

Answer (score 2):

I have not used TextMate, but going through their [manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/), I believe one of these plugins is what you're looking for

- [NERD tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)
- [Fuzzy finder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)
- [Lusty explorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890)

I personally use NERD tree and Fuzzy finder and they're both phenomenal! Do give them a try.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Waldo](https://github.com/jtaby/Waldo).

Comment: Wow, this looks very promising! Can we hope for the replace functionality as well?

Comment: Ask for this feature request on github. But i think that is not the project intention.

Answer (score 1):

If you like fuzzyfinder.vim you might want to have a look at [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T) as well.

> The Command-T plug-in provides an
>   extremely fast, intuitive mechanism
>   for opening files and buffers with a
>   minimal number of keystrokes. It's
>   named "Command-T" because it is
>   inspired by the "Go to File" window
>   bound to Command-T in TextMate.

[Here](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) you can view some screencasts with demos of the plugin.